# How to retrieve array of users from Parse using array of ObjectIds?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

So I'm currently running into an issue where I need to retrieve an array of users from my parse.com database. I have an array of objectIds that I want to query on to get these results.

I've searched everywhere on the internet, and unfortunately none of the solutions have worked.

I've tried creating a PFQuery that queries on the key "objectId", but for some reason this doesn't work (With any object type).

There was also a suggestion in this link: [Suggestion Link On Parse Forums](https://parse.com/questions/how-to-retrive-multiple-objects-with-key-as-objectid-in-an-array)

I have my swift code set up to resemble this, but I'm just receiving blank PFUsers from parse. I debugged a bit, and it appears that none of the "partner" objects in my for loop are getting created with objectIds. I even tried setting them manually as you can see.

I don't know if I'm going about this wrong, or my syntax is just off. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
func queryForPartners(partnerIds : [NSString])
{

    var query = PFQuery(className: "User")

    var tempArrayOfObjects : [PFObject] = []
    for partnerId in partnerIds
    {
        var partner: PFUser = PFUser.objectWithoutDataWithObjectId(partnerId as String)
        partner.objectId = partnerId as String
        tempArrayOfObjects.append(partner)
    }
    PFUser.fetchAllInBackground(tempArrayOfObjects, block: { (objects, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            // The find succeeded.
            println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) Users.")
            self.usersForCells.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
            if let objects = objects as? [PFUser] {
                for object in objects {
                    self.usersForCells.append(object)
                }
            }

        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            println("Error: \(error) \(error!.userInfo!)")
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: How are you testing that they're blank users? Is any error returned?

Comment: By blank users I mean that when I'm stepping through the debugger, I pause on the line "tempArrayOfObjects.append(partner)" and in my PFObject, I look through all the different values in that object, and none of them have any values. In particular, the objectId, which I thought was what would have been set when the object was created, or when I set it manually the line above.

Comment: Have you called `objectForKey:` on the objects ?

Comment: Could you describe what you mean by that? I'm not familiar with how that function works.

Answer (score 0):

start by simplifying your user query. This will query your user class:

```
var query = PFUser.query()
```

In your query, check the "objectId" key against the array of partnerIds you have stored already. I'm assuming partnerIds is an array of strings. This code is basically saying: "check every user you have stored. If the user's objectId is in partnerIds, return it."

```
query?.whereKey("objectId", containedIn: partnerIds)
```

Run your query:

```
query?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (NSArray objects, NSError error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            if let objects = objects {
                // Do something with your users
            }
        } else {
            println("An error occurred")
        }
    })
```